# Как удалять элементы списка с вложенными компонентами и useReducer в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Это главный метод:

```
import './App.css';
import Form from './Components/Form/Form';
import Button from './Components/Button/Button';
import Checklist from './Components/Checklist/Checklist';
import { useReducer } from 'react';

const updater = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'addTask':
      return [...state, action.payload]; // state.push(action.payload);
    case 'deleteTask':
      // return [...state(0, 3), ...state(5, end)]
  }

  throw new Error('Undefined action type');
}

function App() {
  const [tasks, dispatchTasks] = useReducer(updater, []);

  /* [{
            id: useId(),
            title: taskTitle
        }]
  */

  return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={(taskData) => dispatchTasks({type: 'addTask', payload: taskData})}></Form>
      <Button>All</Button>
      <Button>Done</Button>
      <Button>Remainded</Button>
      <Checklist tasks={tasks}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Это отрисовка формы:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import InputTypeText from "../InputTypeText/InputTypeText";
import styles from "./Form.module.scss";

function Form({onSubmit}) {
    const formRef = useRef(null);
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    const inputName = 'task title';
    const getId = () => Date.now();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const form = formRef.current;
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        const taskTitle = formData.get(inputName);

        if (taskTitle === '') return;

        const input = inputRef.current;
        input.value = '';

        onSubmit({
            id: `${taskTitle}_${getId()}`,
            title: taskTitle
        });
    }

    return (
        <form ref={formRef}>
            <InputTypeText name={inputName} ref={inputRef}/>
            <Button clickHandler={handleSubmit}>Add</Button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Form;
```

Это отрисовка списка:

```
import ChecklistItem from "./ChecklistItem/ChecklistItem";

function Checklist({tasks}) {

    return (
        <ul>
            {
                tasks.map(taskData => <ChecklistItem taskData={taskData} key={taskData.id}/>)
            }
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Checklist;
```

это добавление элемента в список:

```
import { useId } from 'react';
import Button from '../../Button/Button';

function ChecklistItem({
    taskData
}) {
    const id = useId();

    return (
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id={id}/>
            <label htmlFor={id}>{taskData.title}</label>
            <Button>Edit</Button>
            <Button>Delete</Button>
        </li>
    )
}

export default ChecklistItem;
```

Это просто элемент кнопки:

```
import "./Button.module.scss"

function Button({clickHandler, children}) {
    return(
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>{children}</button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

Получается вот такое:

[image: screen]

Я уже добавил 1 тестовый элемент, чтобы было видно как он выглядит.

При нажатии Delete в списке должен удаляться элемент, на котором он был нажат.

Я только обучаюсь ReactJS  и не очень понимаю пока, как делать удаление.
Прошу помочь и объяснить как.

Comment: [Добавление/удаление строк и столбцоа в react](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2/1504703#1504703)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так - протянуть функцию от списка в `App` до кнопки удаления, в кнопке передать `id` . Особо обратить внимание, что в `App` редьюсер управляет состоянием и настраивать нужно с его учетом.

Тот вариант что предложен в комментариях - это для одноуровневого компонента и без учета useReducer. В случае более глубокой вложенности не подходит.

```js
const updater = (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'addTask':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'deleteTask': 
      return [...state.filter(current => current.id !== action.payload.id)]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
function Form({onSubmit}) {
    const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

    const inputName = 'task title';
    const getId = () => Date.now();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (inputRef.current.value === '') return;
        
        let taskTitle = inputRef.current.value;
        inputRef.current.value = '';

        onSubmit({
            id: `${taskTitle}_${getId()}`,
            title: taskTitle
        });
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <InputTypeText name={inputName} ref={inputRef}/>
            <Button clickHandler={handleSubmit}>Add</Button>
        </form>
    )
}

function Button({clickHandler, children}) {
    return(
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>{children}</button>
    )
}

const InputTypeText = React.forwardRef(({name}, ref) => {
    return(
        <input name={name} ref={ref}/>
    )
})

function Checklist({tasks, onDel}) {
  return (
      <ul>
          {
            tasks.map(taskItem => <ChecklistItem taskData={taskItem} key={taskItem.id} clickHandler={onDel}/>)
          }
      </ul>
  )
}

function ChecklistItem({taskData, clickHandler }) {
    return (
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id={taskData.id}/>
            <label htmlFor={taskData.id}>{taskData.title}</label>
            <Button>Edit</Button>
            <Button clickHandler={() => clickHandler({id: taskData.id})}>Delete</Button>
        </li>
    )
}


function App() {
  const tasksData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Заголовок1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Заголовок2',
    }
  ]

  const [tasks, dispatchTasks] = React.useReducer(updater, tasksData);
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={(taskData) => dispatchTasks({type: 'addTask', payload: taskData})}></Form>
      <Button>All</Button>
      <Button>Done</Button>
      <Button>Remainded</Button>
      <Checklist tasks={tasks} onDel={(taskData) => dispatchTasks({type: 'deleteTask', payload: taskData})}/>
    </div>
  )
}
  
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: То есть удаление в React делается с помощью !== ?

Comment: Мне сложно понять как сделать удаление элемента списка когда список за пределами form а кнопка удаления у каждого элемента списка

Comment: И как мне передать taskData когда у меня нет такого? У меня же на странице уже добавляются элементы в список

Comment: А всё я понял! Спасибо большое, при просмотре неразделённого кода сильно запутался а потом понял что происходит. Спасибо вам. Дальше у учителя уточню как в принципе само удаление в React работает

Comment: это не удаление, это фильтр и как бы полное переприсвоение - стараются делать так. Если ответ решил вашу проблему - отметьте пожалуйста, решением и проголосуйте.